# GParted after upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS (WinXP on same HDD)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, gparted

I have been rnning Ubuntu 12.04LTS and WinXP on one disk (grub booting), no probs.
Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and since the the gparted doesn't start (via "sudo gparted"):
the window opens but there is a bar going back and forth saying: "dev/sda/ are being searched" (translated from German /dev/sda/ wird durchsucht").

the following is displayed in the terminal:

```
computer@computer:~$ sudo gparted

no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory

libparted : 2.3
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 29 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 34 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 33 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 37 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 36 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 40 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 39 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 43 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 42 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 48 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 47 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 51 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 50 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 54 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 53 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 59 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 58 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 62 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 61 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 65 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 64 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 73 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 72 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 76 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 75 was not found when attempting to remove it
(gpartedbin:11255): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g_convert_error
code  : 1
what  : Ungültige Bytefolge in Konvertierungseingabe
```

I didn't find anything in google to help...
I am a beginner and running out of ideas how to solve that....

Thanks in advance!

Greets,
tobi

Comment: Do not use sudo with graphical apps. use gksudo gparted. And even then launching from terminal often shows an error or two, but not what you are getting. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo

Comment: Seemingly I am stupid... I am sure gparted worked with unmounted drives before, but with new Ubuntu I have to mount all drives before gparted starts. Thanks for the fast reply an the hint with gksudo!

Comment: You might look at the GParted FAQ entry on [Why does "Scanning all devices..." or "Searching /dev/sda partitions" take exceedingly long on some computers?](http://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-11)(.